# Parameter Missing C#, MYSQL (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

`enter code here`I'm stuck with the error of missing Parameter "@comment". However, I am sure that it is not a null value and I had all the necessary values being passed into the respective parameters.

After scanning the codes for hours, I'm sure that my SQL command is not missing "@comment" which the error stated.

The main program will call for the method below and pass in the respective values to the method. Based on these attributes values, it will call 1 of the 8 sql command to be used.

Any advice on what to do in such cases? Thanks.

I used the below codes to validate my attributes values before passing them to the method.

```
//-------Checklist 5-------
        itemID = "dnaIN"; type = "in";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblD5.Text) == false)
        { objR.CheckBy = lblD5.Text; }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblD5.Text) == true)
        { objR.CheckBy = "0"; }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblV5.Text) == false)
        { objR.VerifiedBy = lblV5.Text; }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblV5.Text) == true)
        { objR.VerifiedBy = "0"; }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblsbC.Text) == false) // check if user type comments
        { objR.Comment = lblsbC.Text; }
        else
        { objR.Comment = "0"; }
        update = objR.update(formID, itemID, type);
```

//----------Pass to the codes below----------

```
string strConn = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InternshipConnectionString"]);
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();

//program pass in 0 as null for checkby & verifiedby
if (_CheckBy != "0" && _VerifiedBy != "0" && type == "in") // user enter everything, system in 
{
cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemIn SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy =@verifiedBy WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
 }

 else if (_CheckBy != "0" && _VerifiedBy == "0" && type == "in") // user enter checkBy only, 
 {
 cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemIn SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy = NULL WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
 }
 else if (type == "in")
 {   
 cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemIn SET CheckBy = NULL, VerifiedBy =NULL WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
  }

  else if (_CheckBy != "0" && _VerifiedBy != "0" && _Comment != "0" && type == "out") 
  {
  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemOut SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy =@verifiedBy, Comment=@comment WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
  }
  else if (_CheckBy != "0" && _VerifiedBy == "0" && _Comment == "0" && type == "out") 
  {
  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemOut SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy = NULL, Comment=NULL WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
  }
  else if (_CheckBy != "0" && _Comment != "0" && _VerifiedBy == "0" && type == "out")
  {
  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemOut SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy=NULL, Comment=@comment WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
  }
  else if (_CheckBy != "0" && _Comment == "0" && _VerifiedBy != "0" && type == "out")
  {
  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemOut SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy =@verifiedBy, Comment=NULL WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
   }
   else if (type == "out")
   {   
   cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemOUT SET CheckBy = NULL, VerifiedBy = NULL, Comment=NULL WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);
    }

    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formID", formID);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemID", itemID);

    if (_CheckBy != "0")
    { cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkBy", _CheckBy); }
    if (_VerifiedBy != "0")
    { cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@verifiedBy", _VerifiedBy); }
    if (_Comment != "0")
    { cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", _Comment); }
```

Comment: What is your `SqlCommand` looks like at the end?

Comment: what do u meant by look at the end? @Soner Gonul

Comment: conn.Open();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

Comment: No it is not that. When you debug your code, what is your `cmd1` looks like in the debugger before you execute it? (Before `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()` line)

Comment: The parameterized query '(@formID int,@userName nvarchar(10),@computerName nvarchar(13),@' expects the parameter '@comment', which was not supplied.

You mean this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the last two lines in your code are what matters to your error message.
`@comment` will be missing only if `_Comment` is `"0"`.
If you always have to pass `@comment`, then change it to this:

```
if (_Comment != "0")
    { cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", _Comment); }
else
    { cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", null); }
```

Comment: But i did my validations to check if "comment" is null before passing it in. if it's null, i will pass "0" to "comment" to tell the method. From there, i will use my if-else() and make the Comment = NULL in query. is this correct?

Comment: In the checklist, you told it "if it's null, set it to zero".  Then in the execution you said "if it's not zero, pass it on as parameter". You never told it what to do if it's zero, which is the case if it's null in the checklist.

Comment: So my answer will ensure there will always be parameter `@comment` even if the user types nothing.

Comment: true that. But i did the code below to tell what to do if it's "0"

else if (_CheckBy != "0" && _Comment == "0" && _VerifiedBy != "0" && type == "out")
  {
  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SystemOut SET CheckBy =@checkBy, VerifiedBy =@verifiedBy, Comment=NULL WHERE FormID =@formID AND ItemID =@itemID", conn);

It does the same thing checking/validation right?

Comment: anyway, i edited the codes to based on your suggestion. But i'm still stuck at the same error. any tips on how to fixed this?

Comment: Your mixing of `Comment=NULL` and conditionally adding `@comment` makes it possible for this error; if the code falls into the case of `else if(type == "out")`, then the query string has no `@comment`, but then you may be adding it later with `AddWithValue()`. So you have to make sure that if you're adding `@comment`, you supply the parameter-value, and if you're NOT adding `@comment`, don't supply the parameter-value.  More than one case can cause that error for you. Break into your code and see where execution falls into to correct the code execution path.

Comment: Yeah, i ensure that requirement by checking the value of "comment". when comment != "0", the query statement will include comment=@comment. when comment == "0", the query becomes comment = comment. it works on my other methods but somehow it just got stuck here man.

Comment: Good morning Bro. yeah, i heed your advice and restructure the codes now and it worked! Thanks bro!